# Is the category of abelian presheaves on a topos closed?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, abelian-categories, topos-theory

Take the category of presehaves of abelian groups on a topos $\mathcal{C}$. That is, an object of our category is a functor $F: \mathcal{C}^{\operatorname{op}} \to \operatorname{Ab}$.

We have a clear definition of a symmetric tensor product by $(F \otimes G)(S) = F(S) \otimes G(S)$.

However, defining an appropriate internal hom seems trickier. Taking inspiration from the internal sheaf hom, it seems like it would make sense to define

$${\mathscr{H}\kern -.5pt om} (F,G)(S) = \operatorname{Hom}(F_{| \mathcal{C}/S}, G_{|\mathcal{C}/S})$$

where $\mathcal{C}/S$ is the slice category. However, I can't seem to prove the adjunction (if it is even true). The main problem is that the slice category is more difficult to work with than in a general topos. Could there be some stronger requirements on the topos to make sure the adjunction is satisfied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The category of abelian presheaves is locally finitely presentable, and for each abelian presheaf $F$, the functor $F \otimes {-}$ preserves colimits, so we may apply the accessible adjoint functor theorem to obtain a right adjoint $\mathscr{H}om (F, -)$.
Representability of the functor $H \mapsto H (S)$ can be used to determine the values of $\mathscr{H}om (F, G)$:
$$\mathscr{H}om (F, G) (S) \cong \textrm{Hom} (F \otimes \mathbb{Z} h_S, G)$$
Here $h_S = \mathcal{C} (-, S)$ and $\mathbb{Z} h_S$ is the free abelian presheaf generated by $h_S$.

Actually, your formula is also correct.
The point is that you need to verify that
$$\textrm{Hom} (F \otimes \mathbb{Z} h_S, G) \cong \textrm{Hom} (F |_{\mathcal{C}_{/ S}},  G |_{\mathcal{C}_{/ S}})$$
which can be done essentially the same way as the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: Would there be a way to explicitly define the isomorphism between the hom-sets?

Comment: Everything here can be made explicit. It's just a matter of choosing some good notation.

Comment: I have been trying to find an explicit construction but haven't arrived to anything so far. That is, given a map $F \otimes H \to G$ construct a map $F \to {\mathscr{H}\kern -.5pt om}(H, G)$ but I am struggling to see a natural way to do this.

Comment: It's not substantially different from the usual hom-tensor adjunction. Roughly speaking it is given by the formula $a \mapsto (f \mapsto (h \otimes s \mapsto a (f \otimes h)))$, when we define $\mathscr{H}om (H, G) = \textrm{Hom}(H \otimes \mathbb{Z} h_S, G)$.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand that formula. I assume that for a given section, you are taking $f \in F(S)$, and this must map to an element in $\operatorname{Hom} (H \otimes \mathbb{Z} h_S, G)$. The bit $h \otimes s \mapsto a(f \otimes h)$ is what confuses me, since $f \in F(S)$ so you must have $h \in H(S)$. How do you define it for the rest of the sections?

Comment: No. Given an $a : F \otimes H \to G$, I need to give you some morphism $F \to \mathscr{H}om (H, G)$. Such a thing takes elements of $F (S)$ to give morphisms $H \otimes \mathbb{Z} h_S \to G$. Such a thing consists of maps $H (T) \otimes \mathbb{Z} \mathcal{C} (T, S) \to G (T)$. The formula $h \otimes s \mapsto a (f \otimes h)$ defines such a map for all $T$. Put those together. etc.

Comment: After checking this very carefully, I think it might be more accurate to say $a \mapsto (f \mapsto (h \otimes s \mapsto a(s^* f \otimes h)))$ where $s^*$ is the map induced by $s$.

Comment: Also adding the following link for completion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18355/internal-hom-of-sheaves